# How do I add a where clause to a field that is not part of the return set for LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm wondering how I would add a dynamic where clause on my linq query where the field I'm filtering on is not part of the return set.

Query:

```
(from p in db.Person
join c in db.Client on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId into c_join
from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join pt in db.PersonType on p.PersonTypeId equals pt.PersonTypeId into pt_join
from pt in pt_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join pl in db.Plan on c.ClientId equals pl.ClientId into pl_join
from pl in pl_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join plt in db.PlanType on pl.PlanTypeId equals plt.PlanTypeId into plt_join
from plt in plt_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby pt.PersonTypeDescription ascending , p.LastName ascending
select new ExtendedPersonSearch
{
PersonId = p.PersonId,
FirstName = p.FirstName,
LastName = p.LastName,
MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
Aka = p.Aka,
Sin = p.Sin,
PersonTypeId = pt.PersonTypeId,
PersonTypeDescription = pt.PersonTypeDescription,
ClientId = (Int32?) c.ClientId
}).Distinct();
```

Related Class:

```
 public class ExtendedPersonSearch
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Aka { get; set; }
        public string Sin { get; set; }
        public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }
        public string PersonTypeDescription { get; set; }
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
```

But, I want to do a filter on pl.PlanId which is not part of the ExtendedPersonSearch class.

These other types of dynamic where clauses work for items inside the return set:

```
 if (fd.Contains("txtSearchFirstName"))
                {
                    var searchFirstName = form[fd];
                    ViewData["searchFirstName"] = searchFirstName;

                    if (searchFirstName != "")
                        qryAllPerson = qryAllPerson.Where(sp => sp.FirstName.Contains(searchFirstName));

                }
```

Short of writing the query again based on whether or not a user entered a plan id in order to get this query:

```
qryAllPerson = (from p in db.Person
join c in db.Client on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId into c_join
from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join pt in db.PersonType on p.PersonTypeId equals pt.PersonTypeId into pt_join
from pt in pt_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join pl in db.Plan on c.ClientId equals pl.ClientId into pl_join
from pl in pl_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join plt in db.PlanType on pl.PlanTypeId equals plt.PlanTypeId into plt_join
from plt in plt_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby pt.PersonTypeDescription ascending, p.LastName ascending
where pl.PlanId == searchPlanId
select new ExtendedPersonSearch
{
PersonId = p.PersonId,
FirstName = p.FirstName,
LastName = p.LastName,
MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
Aka = p.Aka,
Sin = p.Sin,
PersonTypeId = pt.PersonTypeId,
PersonTypeDescription = pt.PersonTypeDescription,
ClientId = (Int32?)c.ClientId
}).Distinct();
```

Is there a way that I can just tack on the where clause for the PlanId instead of having to put in the entire query again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other dynamic searches work because they are properties on your extended search class.

When you run your query, you're getting back an enumerable of ExtendedPersonSearch objects. Once you get this back, you can only filter by properties that exist on that object.

Just like in real life, you couldn't filter your pets by the number of CPU cores they have (it simply doesn't make sense.)

If you want a single query, you could modify the line

```
where pl.PlanId == searchPlanId
```

to be

```
where (searchPlanId == null || pl.PlanId == searchPlanId)
```

That way if no search plan is entered, the first part of the conditional is hit and it short circuits and returns all records. If a search plan id is entered, the first clause is false, and so C# would go to the second clause and make sure that pl.PlanId does equal the entered searchPlanId.

Or you could add PlanId to the ExtendedPersonSearch object and filter on it after you retrieve from the data source. But this probably isn't the best idea, as you'll be pulling back a lot of data only to throw away most of it once you filter out the results that don't match the plan id.